# SonicWall global vpn

Tags: vpn, network

I have a SonicWall device, and I am new to them.
I created the global vpn and, after installing the SonicWall at the customer's site, wanted to make some configuration changes. I am using the global vpn client and I get connected to the SonicWall. I get an IP address from the SonicWall but I do not know how to access the SonicWall once connected. How can I access the SonicWall? 192.168.1.1 is the IP address for administrating the SonicWall, and it is also the default gateway.  My own subnet is 192.168.199.1.  So, how does it work? Do I need to enable or disbale something, or is there another way to do it? I tried putting 192.168.1.1 into Chrome to access it, and tried to ping it from my PC, but neither of those worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to reach the firewall using its LAN address (192.168.1.1). However, in order to be able to manage the SonicWall over the VPN connection, you must enable this in the VPN config:

```
vpn policy group-vpn "WAN GroupVPN"                    
    management https                                   
    exit
```

In the web interface you can find this in the advanced tab when you edit the VPN settings:
[image: SonicWall VPN settings]

Firewall rules (VPN > LAN) for management should be auto-added when you do this, but be sure to check:
[image: auto-added VPN rule]